# How to make an Android application to run some UI element above other application?

Tags: java, android

Sorry if the title is it's not self explanatory.

I'm trying to make an application that can interact with other ones by adding them a graphic element in their UI.

Just like Google does with Google Translate new function. 
You can see a graphic example here: [EXAMPLE GIVEN](http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2016/05/TTT_DogfoodGif_v01_JRS.gif)

My questions are:

- Is that even possible? (I guess it is)
- Where can I start searching about this? I haven't seen anything in Androids Developer documentation. I really don't know how to search info about this.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to add a graphic element to your app, I suggest using the Toolbar widget (it's automatically added with the Basic Activity template). There's also the ActionBar, but I think the toolbar is preferred to use (newer).

You can get a better idea about it here.
https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html/

As far as the behavior of the icons, you'll have to add your own logic to them. Intents (implicit/explicit) are one way to interact with other things.

I hope this helps push you in the right direction.

Comment: I think that what he needs is to show up some pop-up element outside its own application. Action and toolbars are just basic design elements that can't handle this.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood him then. Maybe a custom FloatingActionButton then?

Comment: @Ryan Sorry if I didn´t explain myself. I want to know how to draw an element on other application while mine is running on background. Just like in the example I gave: translate some text with Google Translate without leaving whatsapp. The problem is not on what element should I use but how I show that element on an application it's not mine.

Comment: No worries! I'm not entirely sure how Google Translate works, but if I were to guess, I'd say it uses BroadcastReceivers to capture intents, which would then open its application. As for the GUI component, you'll probably want to create a Floating Action Button (FAB).

To be more clear: A user touches the screen and selects text to copy to Android's Clipboard Manager >> GT's Broadcast Receiver grabs the intent from Clipboard Manager >> GT's Floating Action Button pops up on the screen >> User can now conveniently interact with GT.